# why we use same learning rate in the whole process of the gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, supervised-learning

[image: gradient descent]

In theory, we know while we are descending to the point where the error is zero, we give big steps that are learning rate will be big. And when we are near to the error equal to zero we start giving small steps that are learning rate will be small. But, whatever the theory is we use the same learning rate whole over the Gradient descent process. Could anyone help me to explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**We don't** always use the same learning rate; almost the opposite in my experience. Your learning resources are probably starting off with vanilla gradient descent because it is easier to understand at first, and then knowing gradient descent sets you up to start learning about its modifications (including those that change the learning rate).

Both [adaptive learning rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_rate#Adaptive_learning_rate) and [learning rate schedules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_rate#Learning_rate_schedule) are quite common. I personally use [Adam](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980)([`tf.keras.optimizers.Adam`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adam)) and Nadam ([`tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Nadam)) among others. And [`tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/LearningRateScheduler) is Keras/Tensorflow callback for making your own custom learning rate schedules.

Comment: @Gelen the links you came all are on the learning rate scheduler. So, you meant the learning rate scheduler helps to have different learning rates from time to time?

Comment: @F.C.Akhi Look at the contents of that wiki. There is a section on adaptive learning rates, not just learning rate schedules.

Comment: @ So, adaptive learning rate and learning rate schedules are two methods that help to tune learning rate from time to time, Is it something like that?

Comment: @F.C.Akhi Yeah, something like that. They both change the learning rate anyway, but the term "tune" is not synonymous with these changes.

Comment: So they are the learning rate optimizer?

Comment: These two methods are part of optimization strategies, but they are not optimizing the learning rate *per se*. Rather they help set the learning rate to improve the process of optimizing the loss function.

Comment: Now I understood. Thank you

Comment: @F.C.Akhi If I answered your question, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark.